# How to bulk insert using Sequelize bulkCreate

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I used Nestjs to build a new backend server.
It need bulk insert feature and I execute it with Sequelize

```js
export class OwnerService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Owner)
    private ownerRepository: typeof Owner,
    @InjectModel(Wallet)
    private walletRepository: typeof Wallet,
  ) {}
  async bulkCreate(data: Owner[]) {
    this.ownerRepository.bulkCreate(data);
  }
}
```

Owner Entity

```js
@Table({ tableName: 'owner' })
export class Owner extends Model {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  address: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    field: 'public_key',
  })
  publicKey: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Wallet, () => WalletOwner)
  wallets: Wallet[];
}
```

TS throws the error:

```
Argument of type 'Owner[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly Optional<any, string>[]'.
Type 'Owner' is not assignable to type 'Optional<any, string>'.
Type 'Owner' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
Index signature for type 'number' is missing in type 'Owner'
```

I also tried the interface type

```js
interface OwnerInterface {
  name: string;

  address: string;

  publicKey: string;
}
```

But the result is still the same.

How can I solve it ?

Is it only one way to solve it as official doc?

```js
this.ownerRepository.bulkCreate([
{name: "name1", address: "address1", publicKey: "publicKey1"},
{name: "name2", address: "address2", publicKey: "publicKey2"},
]);
```

Comment: You should have an interface for creation that contains only attributes need for creation

Comment: @Anatoly the OwnerInterface is what like you said?

Comment: I kept in mind that approach from the docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/#usage
I'm not sure about sequelize-typescript package but I suppose you should search for the way to do the same thing using its decorators

Comment: I have a bad solution for this, just do this `async bulkCreate(data: any) {
    this.ownerRepository.bulkCreate(data);
  }`